# Change google map icon image after a specified time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, extjs4.2

I am using extjs v4.2 with GMapPanel.js (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8172299) and google maps V3 API.

My markers are being placed fine. What I would like to do is after a given time say 10 seconds, change the marker icon image for a specific marker.

Here is the file (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8172388) that initializes the markers however I believe the changes are made in GMapPanel.js

I use the clear marker when the map initially loads, then I would like to see it changed to a green marker after a given time (10 seconds)

One line #53 of GMapPanel.js is where the markers are initially loaded.

On line #54 I have tried to change the marker (without any timer just simply trying change the markers).

If anyone can tell me how to change the icon I would be really appreciative. I hope this question is clear enough, please let me know if you need anymore information.

Cheers.

Comment: Use setTimeout() to set an event (code to execute) after a specified amount of time. Ex. setTimeout( "yourJSfunction()", time_in_ms )

Comment: Thanks for the answer about the timer. That's not actually the critical question I was asking about. The changing of the marker icon is what I would like to know.

Comment: Also, why on earth has some fool marked my question down. I think it's a very clear question with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GMapPanel` has a `mapready` event, register for it and get map object of gmap v3 api and then you can implement gmap v3 google api based functions etc. e.g

```
mapready : function(map, eOpts) {
                    var mapObj = map.gmap;
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map : mapObj,
                    draggable : true,
                    animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position : new google.maps.LatLng(38.410558, -98.525391)
                    });
                 setTimeout(function(){marker.setIcon('newImage.png');}, 2000);

                }
```

The above code is untested. Just to give an idea.

Comment: Thanks very much. This looks like a great place to start. I see the map ready being fired after the initialization. Thanks for the example code. It's starting to make sense now. I take it that you cannot place a marker on top of another one (exact lat/lng). Is this how I replace the one that was there previously or do I have to clear the map first?

Comment: Instead of using ExtJS for all map operations, i always prefer to initialize map from extjs and then do everything including event listening, markers, polygons etc from map object. In this way you will get more help from google map community and lot of examples online

Comment: Thanks again TheRaaaZ. I achieved what I set out to achieve with you help. I didn't manage to get it working with the map ready like you suggested. When i console.log(mapready) I got true but it still didn't allow me to use mapready : function. However, I made it work a different way and it's perfect!